# How to handle an arbitrary large amount of data for a table view? (iOS/Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a situation where I'd like to download more data to display as I scroll down my table view. Currently I figure I could just keep adding the data to an NSMutableArray, and I'm wondering if there's a better way. If I keep scrolling down, my array could potentially get huge and I have a bunch of data sitting there that doesn't even need to be used anymore until I scroll back up.

I've considered the option of releasing and re-downloading parts of the data when appropriate, not sure if this is a common design pattern in dealing with this. The data is very lightweight, just some strings, so the re-downloading option seems viable as the user experience won't get impacted by waiting for the download. More generally, I guess I don't need to worry too much about this specific situation since the data is so lightweight, but it's good to know some general best practices/options anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would just keep adding the data to the NSMutableArray. Why?

The amount of memory needed to store UI-related stuff is *many* times that of simple data classes. That's why UITableView has a reuse mechanism built in from the very first version of iOS. Keep in mind that the user has to make a lot of scroll movements to get to the 1000th row - they probably stop way before that.

If you're really concerned about the memory, you can persist the data with the Core Data framework, and use the `NSFetchedResultsController` class to do exactly what you describe (load only the visible data objects in memory). [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) is a good tutorial on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Core Data. I'm using the cell reuse mechanism already so that part is covered! I guess what you're saying is that amount of downloaded data I'm storing isn't something I should be concerned about.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: just to add a thought: if there's some natural subset the user might want to see, you could provide UI to limit to that (e.g. drill down through categories).  Twitter, for example has a natural subset which is based on recency, just fetching the N most recent, then N again when the scroll offset approaches the content size.